# Microsoft Jet Database engine -- cannot get 'like' to operate as desired

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use the Microsoft Jet database engine to select records from an Excel worksheet.  I want to select only the records in which field F1 contains a forward slash.  My SELECT instruction looks like:

`select F1 from [yada yada] where F1 like '*/*'`

but this results in no records being returned at all.  I've tried using % instead of *, and `alike` instead of `like`, but no combination works.  What is the correct expression for matching on a field based on whether or not it contains a single specified character?
Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible your fields don't actually contain a slash, but display a slash due to formatting? If you select a cell and press F2, what do you see to edit?

Comment: Hmm, good point, I hadn't thought of that, but I just checked and the / character is truly the forward slash character (hex 2F), same as is used in date strings.

Comment: Which version do you use? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719115/microsoft-jet-wildcards-asterisk-or-percentage-sign

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `*/*` with double quotes. `"*/*"` not `'*/*'`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had also tried both single quotes and double quotes, neither has the desired effect.

Comment: I wonder if  you might need to explicitly declare the table.For example this works for me    `SELECT Sheet1.F1 FROM Sheet1 WHERE (((Sheet1.F1) Like "*/*"));`

Answer (score 0):

I did some more searching and found that the Jet database engine uses ANSI SQL 92.  From there I found that the wildcard character for ANSI SQL 92 is `%`, not `*`. I was sure that I had already tried the % character and had found it not to work, but I went back and tried it again.  I found that when I changed the target of the "like" operator from '*/*' to '%/%' that then it worked.
I apologize for including incorrect information in my original statement of the problem.  Thanks to all who looked at it.